# Monthly data of current year in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server for getting the records of sale and purchase all the month of current year but the query I've used doesn't give correct data.

I want the total sum of sale and purchase of all the months of the current year and using group by in query.

The result would be then used in chart

```
SELECT YEAR(Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) [Year], 
       DATENAME(MONTH,Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) [Month Name],
       sum(Purchase_Product.total_Amount) as 'Total'
FROM Purchase_Product
GROUP BY YEAR(Purchase_Product.Purchase_date), 
         DATENAME(MONTH, Purchase_Product.Purchase_date)
having DATEPART(yyyy, Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
ORDER BY 1,2
```

The expected output would be like

```
Year | Month | Total
2019 | January| 90000
2019 | February|120000
2019 | March| 786329
2019 | April| 67237
2019 | May| 96792
2019 | June| 80000
2019 | July| 799000
2019 | August| 1832002
2019 | September| 93822
2019 | October| 97382
2019 | November| 97340
2019 | December| 43000
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Comment: Date-based aggregations become a *lot* easier when you use [a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). Once you do that you can simply join with the calendar table and filter, group by month, year taking full advantage of indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date-based aggregations become a *lot* easier when you use [a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). Once you do that you can simply join with the calendar table and filter, group by month, year taking full advantage of indexes, eg :

```
SELECT DateDimension.YEAR [Year], 
       DateDimension.MontName ,
       sum(Purchase_Product.total_Amount) as 'Total'
FROM Purchase_Product inner join DateDimension 
    on Purchase_Date = DateDimension.Date
GROUP BY 
    DateDimension.Year,
    DateDimension.MonthName
Where 
    DateDimension.Year=YEAR(DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
Order by 
    DateDimension.Year,
    DateDimension.MonthName
```

This query will have very good performance if the `Purchase_Date` and the calendar table columns are covered by indexes.

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos but right now I not working with indexes 
But surely work with it in future and use this one.

Comment: Without indexes the query will have to scan 10 years worth of rows when it only needs a single year. This will cause delays even for a small amount of data

Comment: Thank you @Panagiotis Kanavos for your advice. I'll add indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT YEAR(Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) [Year], 
DATENAME(MONTH,Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) [Month Name], sum(Purchase_Product.total_Amount) as 'Total'
FROM Purchase_Product
where DATEPART(yyyy, Purchase_Product.Purchase_date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()))
GROUP BY YEAR(Purchase_Product.Purchase_date), 
DATENAME(MONTH, Purchase_Product.Purchase_date)
ORDER BY [Year],[Month Name]
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice as to why is OP having the problem and how did your answer solved it. At first glance, the only changes is the `ORDER BY` part

Comment: The performance of this query will be very bad as it won't be able to use any indexes on the date columns.It will force the server to scan the entire table whether the dates match or not.